# FusedLocationApi get location from network

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have written a GPSTracker class with location updates,
everything works fine but it looks like the `onLocationChanged` is called only when there is a change in the GPS status.I want to get the location even if it is from the network.

this is my code for the request,I have also tried the `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` :

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_details_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //building googleapiclient
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        createLocationRequest();
        connect();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        disConnect();
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(3600000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(60000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    }
```